# What dehumidifier should I get for a small bathroom that doesn’t have a great way to evacuate humidity after showers?

Tags: bathroom, shower, humidity, dehumidifier

- Small bathroom
- Has a small left to right sliding window which we open and also have a fan in to try and blow out the humidity
- We currently have a small dehumidifier that does a cup/day in there as well that’s always on

Comment: Is the problem that with the current dehumidifier, the bath is still too humid?  If so please modify your question to reflect that.  Also specs on the dehumidifier that you do have .  We cannot suggest anything bigger if we do not know what is not working.

Comment: Is leaving the bathroom door wide open during and after the shower an option? This website has a bunch of suggestions: https://www.decorrect.com/bathroom-with-no-exhaust-fan/

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a humid climate in a home with no air conditioning, keep the bathroom door and window closed at all times, keep the dehumidifier running, and if you see it producing its *capacity* of water continuously EG it's a pint-a-day machine and you get a pint a day, try buying a bigger one.  In a small bathroom you'll be limited by available space to place the dehumidifier and available electric power ... just buy the largest one that is practical.  Presumably a refrigerant-based floor-standing one is not practical .... but if you can use one, the *smallest* available one will be more than enough (25 pints a day or so probably).

If you are in a dry climate a well-fitted window fan blowing *outwards* should be enough to eliminate humidity from showers and baths in a reasonable time.   To help the fan, keep the door open and open a window in a nearby room to allow through-flow of air.   If that doesn't do the trick, no mini dehumidifier will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If the fan is successful at removing some humidity, just not fast enough, consider upgrading it. I had a small bathroom in my previous house that had serious humidity problems. It had a fan, but it was ineffective, so I ended up having to use a big dehumidifier to keep it dry. As a long-term fix, I installed an upgraded fan with a humidity sensor switch. Bath fans are an area that have had substantial improvement in the last couple of decades. I was able to get a fan that installed from inside the bathroom, connected to the existing four inch duct with an adapter, and moved an amazing amount of air while still being nearly silent. The upgrade took a couple of hours all-in, and totally took care of my humidity problem.